# C# can't open excel file

Tags: c#, excel

When trying to run these lines:

```
var app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(pathToFile, Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

I've got these problems:

1) I'm getting a message of "file conversion is in progress". Why do I need to convert something if all I want to do is just read a column from one of the work sheets.

2) I'm getting this error message: [image]

why do I need to care which version created the excel?

3) In the very end I get an exception: "Too many different cell formats".

So is there something wrong with the way I'm using the open workbook method or is there another way to read a specific column from an excel file which contains several sheets and I only need to read data from a single specific sheet?

Comment: I assume your Interop DLL isn't the correct version for the file you're opening. Try finding a newer one?

Comment: My guess, this error message came directly from excel, no problem in interop. Have you tried opening that file manually?

Comment: The error message here is one of the more descriptive ones I have seen from microsoft and it seems to explain itself.  @nhrobin most likely the version of the interop he is using will be comparable to the version of Excel he is running so yes he should get the same error I think opening it manually

Comment: It did came directly from excel.. Is there a way around it if all I need to do is just reading some data from the workbook?

Comment: What format is the file, and what version is your excel?

Comment: the format is xlsm and I still got office 2003 on this station

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might not be obvious to you but calling

```
new Excel.Application()
```

opens an instance of Excel (you may check it on the Task Manager). So if your version of Excel is not compatible with the file you are opening you get this error.

Since you are trying to open the Excel document with your Excel application, you DO care of what versions they are.

I think [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) could help you with it.